# Facebook SDK login Popup

Tags: facebook, login, sdk

Tenho um plugin de login pelo facebook, peguei deste tutorial http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/. até aí tudo bem, mas gostaria de coloca-lo pra redirecionar para a mesma página no qual é solicitado o login, já vi muitos sites fazerem isso com popups de autenticação. Como posso adicionar essa função de popup para redirecionar para a mesma página que foi solicitada o login?

Answer (score 0):

Isso do popup que você diz é porque eles usaram o SDK javascript para efetuar o login com o Facebook, e não o PHP , que é o seu caso.

No seu caso você pode fazer o seguinte, no método FacebookRedirectLoginHelper você passa a mesma URL da página de login e nela você verifica se o usuário está vindo de um login do Facebook bem como se o mesmo já está logado.

Por exemplo, no FacebookRedirectLoginHelper numa index.php ficaria:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://seusite/index.php');
...
```

e nela mesmo pra receber/verificar o usuário de volta da página de login do Facebook:

```
if ( !empty($_GET['code']) ){
...
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://seusite/index.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch
...
```

- quando o Facebook retorna do login ele traz essa variável GET

Ps.: Efetuar o login no Facebook usando o SDK javascript é extremamente mais produtivo, quando possível.